# Would killing all sessions in Oracle solve my issue?

Tags: oracle, session, locking

I'm thinking of killing all my oracle sessions: 
[Kill all sessions of a user](https://serverfault.com/questions/107756/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-kill-all-sessions-from-a-specified-user-in-oracle)

to solve my [Issue on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230129/oracle-replacing-package-body-stuck) about not being able to replace a package body.

Would you recommend doing this?

Comment: This is not a programming problem. Voted to close and migrate to DBA.stackexchange as a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 1):

"Recommend"? I *would* (kind of), but you should pay attention to *who* is using your package because you might kill that user in the middle of some processing. That would release the package and you'll be able to compile it, but - not everyone will be happy about it.

If you're about to kill yourself only (pure suicide, eh?), go ahead - you'll easily reconnect afterwards.

That's why you should deploy changes during OFF hours.

Comment: Thanks I restarted the machine(it was asking for a windows update anyway) and I can now run the script. Not sure if i can rely on it working when deployed on other machine/database.